# How to allow user define role to decide a class will take which operation

Tags: c#, class

i have a idea : let object operate base on customer define 's role . but i do not exactly know how to finish it , let me introduce what i want to do .

1 : define a class , for example a employee , class employee have some property like age , height , weight .

2 : employee would have these operations : increase salary , move to higher position , and be fired.

these operation maybe have parameters .

3 : whether a employee should take which operation should base on the user of software 's define , for
 example ,  if user A define :  when a emplyee reach 50 years, he will be fired .
but another user maybe define L when a employee reach 50 years , he will be move to higher position.

4 ： altogether , class 's operation is fixed (all 3 operations) , but the condition can decide take  which operation is not fixed , condition depend on user 's define .  if possible , condition could become infinite .

i am not very familiar with c# class , so i can not find a way to finish it , if someone can give me some advise , it is so appreciate .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a user defined function:

```
class Person
{
  short age;
  double salary;

  Person(short int, double salary)
  {
     this.age = age;
     this.salary = salary;
  }

  void DoSomething(Action<Person> f)
  {
        f(this);
  }
  void IncreaseSalary(double newSalary)
  {
        this.salary = newSalary;
  }
  void Fire()
  {
     // whatever Firing means
  }
  void Promote(Action<Person> f)
  {
     // whatever Promotion means, maybe automatic 50% salary raise?
     this.salary *= 0.5;
  }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
Person p = new Person(50);
p.DoSomething(delegate(person p)
             { 
               if (p.age > 50) 
                 p.Fire(); 
               else  
                 p.Promote();
                });
```

The users or you can define a user specific action depending on a person's attributes and pass it to the DoSomething function.

Btw firing people because of their age is illegal in many countries => ageism ;)

Comment: after reading , i have understand your solution , in my case , i can not hardcode this action : (delegate(person p)
             { 
               if (p.age > 50) 
                 p.Fire(); 
               else  
                 p.Promote();
                });         in program , because the user who will define the role is not programer use this class , but the end user who does not know how to write code , so maybe thing come to how to dynamic create an action or function .

Comment: Ok I understand, in any case he will have to write a pseudo code  that reflects the condition for each action, it will then be up to you to translate it to an Action.